# Full path of a package, \listfiles with path

Tags: packages

Suppose a user has an updated MikTeX installation, but `\listfiles` shows that an outdated package is being used. Is there a way to find out where on the hard drive the old package file is located? Is there something like a `\listfiles` with full paths for a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the file you are looking for you can just search the log. For instance, I just compiled an `article` document which loads `amsmath` and `amsfonts`, however I created an empty file named `amsmath.sty` in the current directory. The terminal shows (a similar structure shows in the `.log` file as well; line breaks added for clarity):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Users\Phelype\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\Phelype\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
(amsmath.sty)
("C:\Users\Phelype\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty")
(table.aux)
(table.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on table.log.
```

Notice that `amsmath` (the one which I made a wrong copy of) shows as `(amsmath.sty)`, while `amsfonts` is loaded from the texmf tree: `("C:\Users\Phelype\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty")`.